# New Gmail UI was build using which front-end programming language?

Tags: web, gmail, programming-languages

The new Gmail UI looks cool. I heard that Google used Polymer to build Youtube new UI and AngularDart to build Adsense dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

According to the information that can be extracted when loading the DOM, these are

**Framework JavaScript**

- Lazy.js
- Deployd

**Framework Web**

- Yii

**Server Web**

- OpenGSE

**Programming language**

- Java
- PHP

Comment: PHP? You can't be serious :D I strongly  doubt Google uses PHP.

Comment: Check with chorme extension wappalyzer, some src serve with PHP, Clearly the google server is always GSE

Comment: I'm digging around for this too.  There's this post:

 https://medium.com/@cramforce/designing-very-large-javascript-applications-6e013a3291a3

Which seems to indicate they have their own *framework* they use to make large frontend systems more digestible.

According to the documentation, they also use Closure:

 https://developers.google.com/closure/library/?csw=1

..no word on which *language* though.